# Drop in performance between stanford nlp 3.7.0 and 3.9.2

Tags: stanford-nlp

There seems to be a performance drop between in java for stanford nlp version 3.7.0 and 3.9.2.

I am running the following pipeline

`props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, ner, parse, sentiment");`

and the following properties

```
props.put("ner.model",
            "edu/stanford/nlp/models    /ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
props.put("ner.useSUTime", "false");
props.put("ner.applyNumericClassifiers", "false");
```

When I upgraded from version 3.7.0 to 3.9.2 I am seeing CPU spikes and a fall in performance. Don't have numbers at the minute but seems to be around 5 times slower.

I am parsing small amount of text. A small news site article.

Maybe I should be using a different model?
Anyone else notice this?

Edit:
I have noticed that the 3.9.2 version loads model data for RegexNERAnnotator but 3.7.0 does not, seen this in the logs, not sure if this has an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reason is the rules-based NER is run by default now.

If you don't want the fine-grained named entities, you can deactivate it with

`props.put("ner.applyFineGrained", "false");`

Comment: Thanks for your response. What are fined grained named entities? I am just looking for people and organisations. What's the best source of information for the properties and what they do?

Comment: Would it be possible to get a response to the questions in my last comments? It would be great to have this information rather than ask questions everytime. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The fine-grained named entities are more specific versions of the tags the statistical model finds.  For instance LOCATION --> (CITY, STATE_OR_PROVINCE, COUNTRY)

Comment: There is more info here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html ...go to the section on Fine Grained NER